Quarkus Kubernetes 3.12.3 does not add annotation to ingress in kind.yml
I have a quarkus application that defines kubernetes custom ingress annotation :
quarkus.kubernetes.ingress.annotations."nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target"=/$2

That's not an unusual annotation, when you want to expose your service on a different context-root than /. I want to deploy on kind.
Annotation is present in kubernetes.yml but not in kind.yml.
I expect having the annotation in kind.yml.
Here is my application.properties :
quarkus.kubernetes.namespace=guess
quarkus.kubernetes.env.vars.guess-kafka-url=kafka-svc.kafka.svc.cluster.local:9092
quarkus.kubernetes.ingress.expose=true
quarkus.kubernetes.ports.http.path=/game(/|$)(.*)
quarkus.kubernetes.idempotent=true
quarkus.kubernetes.ingress.annotations."nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target"=/$2

Here are the relevant dependencies :
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
  <artifactId>quarkus-container-image-docker</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
  <artifactId>quarkus-kubernetes</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
  <artifactId>quarkus-kind</artifactId>
</dependency>

In target/kubernetes/kubernetes.yml, I have the annotation :
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    app.quarkus.io/quarkus-version: 3.12.3
    app.quarkus.io/vcs-uri: https://git...
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
  labels:

In target/kubernetes/kind.yml, I do not have the annotation :
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    app.quarkus.io/quarkus-version: 3.12.3
    app.quarkus.io/vcs-uri: https://git...
  labels:

Do I miss something ? Or is this a known bug ?
Thanks in advance,
Christophe

Sounds like a bug, please open an issue on GitHub

Done
https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/42294
